# I am able to start the app in background in Android 10 but not in Android 12 (android-beacon-library)

Tags: android, beacon, android-12

**Expected behavior**

The app should be waked up and run in background periodically in Android 12 same as Android 10.

**Actual behavior**

The app wakes up and run periodically in Android 10 but not in Android 12.

**Steps to reproduce this behavior**

Step 1: open the app
Step 2: kill the app
Step 3: observer logs in the logcat

**Mobile device model and OS version**

Both are Samsung phone, one is OS Android 10 , the other one is OS Android 12

**Android Beacon Library version**

v2.19.4

My code are below:

```
class HewApplication: Application(), RangeNotifier {
  private var beaconManager: BeaconManager? = null
  private val hewRegion = Region("hewRegion", null, null, null)

override fun onCreate() {
  super.onCreate()
  println("ttt HewApplication onCreate...")
  beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(applicationContext)
  beaconManager?.addRangeNotifier(this)
  beaconManager?.startRangingBeacons(hewRegion)
}

override fun didRangeBeaconsInRegion(beacons: MutableCollection?, region: Region?) {
  println("ttt didRangeBeaconsInRegion: beacons: $beacons")
}

}
```

About the permission for Android 12:

android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: true

android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT: true

android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION: true

android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN: true

Comment: In the newer versions of Android, there have been added limitations on what you can do/start from the background(https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#foreground-service-launch-restrictions). How do you wake the app?

Comment: By default you should only get detections every 10-25  minutes in the background using the default Job Scheduler scan strategy.  Have you waited this long?